# pass by reference or not to store link to other instance

Tags: php, constructor, instance, pass-by-reference

At the moment I am working on a parser, comprised of a `Document` class that takes input and determines a number of processing steps to be taken. The logic of each step is dynamic to various circumstances, so is handed off to a `Processor` class which is passed to the `Document` at construction.

The goal is that my use of it will eventually look something like:

```
$document = new Document($input, Processors\XYZ::class);
$document->parse();
$document->output();
```

`Document->__construct()` also creates and stores in a property a new instance of the passed processor class. This leads to the part I am unsure of: The `Processor` instance also needs a link back to the `Document`. I am not sure whether I should be passing that by reference or not. I haven't found anything about this particular use of references - http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php is only really talking about functions, nothing to do with classes or instances.

I threw together this minimal test:

```
class base {
    //function __construct($maker) {
    function __construct(&$maker) {
        if (!is_a($maker, makeSay::class, true)) { echo 'oh no!<br/>';}
        $this->maker = $maker;
    }
    function say() {echo 'Base, made by ' . $this->maker->name;}    
}

class child extends base {
    function say() {echo 'Child, made by ' . $this->maker->name;}
}

class makeSay {
    public $name = 'default';
    function __construct($thing, $name) {
        if (!is_a($thing, base::class, true)) { echo 'oh no!<br/>';}
        $this->thing = new $thing($this);
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    function say() {$this->thing->say();}
}

$a = new makeSay(child::class, 'This Guy');

$a->say();
```

... which has similar logic to the constructors in my real script, but it seems as though there is no difference in execution whether `base->__construct()` looks like `function __construct(&$maker)` or `function __construct($maker)`.

Is there any difference to be expected between the two?

Comment: Classes are always passed by reference. There's no need for `&`. Also in function parameters you can do type-hinting for classes, something like `function __construct(makeSay $variable)` so you don't need to do checks if variable is instance of desired class.

Comment: Thanks very much. I had been about to say I would love to use type hinting but am targeting 5.5, but it turns out that I was incorrect thinking that was a 7 addition. If you want to post as an answer I would definitely tick it